# Duplicate entry 'string1-string2' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

In a Spring MVC application using hibernate and jpa over a MySQL database, I am getting the following error message about a child entity whenever I try to save a parent entity that includes the child entity:

```
Duplicate entry 'string1-string2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Here, `string1` and `string2` refer to the two parts of the composite primary key of the child entity.  **How do I resolve this error?**

Here is the way that the relationship between the entities is defined in the parent `Address` entity:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "usecode", referencedColumnName = "code", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "usecodesystem", referencedColumnName = "codesystem", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
public HL7GeneralCode use;
```

Here is the way the relationship is defined in the child `GeneralCode` entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "use", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<HL7Address> addresses;
```

The complete stack trace can be viewed [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/DOICAvLNvkKbPqLavv4f?b=nlYKLPbTfraHUrQiCFvE).
The complete code for the `Address` entity can be found [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/CIrM6xUfA8aE3x18rRbA).

The complete code for the `GeneralCode` entity can be read [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/FNq5dUa7VyNFGyAz1QGK?b=uTQhpUB2Cr36XYfhVBwY).

The code for the composite primary key class can be found [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/3fichxmdYCTUUVSuEgVx).
And the `BaseEntity` class that is extended by `Address` can be found [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/ml7ziWN7gdrRAwsro9yD).

I have read many postings on this error message.  The answers to the other postings do not resolve my error message, and they generally do not address the fact that my entity uses a **composite primary key**.

---

### **EDIT:**

The code for persisting the address is:

```
@Override
public void savehl7Address(HL7Address addr) {
    if ((Integer)addr.getId() == null) {
        System.out.println("[[[[[[[[[[[[ about to persist address ]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]");
        this.em.persist(addr);}
    else {
        System.out.println("]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]] about to merge address [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[");
        this.em.merge(addr);}
}
```

---

### SECOND EDIT:

I tried to follow @Ben75's advice, but the code is crashing at the line `this.em.persist(addr.getUse());`.  Note that his if clause did not fit my actual object model, so I changed the if clause below to `if(addr.getUse() != null && addr.getId()==null)`.  Here is my code.

```
@Override
public void savehl7Address(HL7Address addr) {
    if(addr.getUse() != null && addr.getId()==null){
        //this next line prints in the stack trace right before the app crashes
        System.out.println("about to this.em.persist(addr.getUse());");
        //HL7GeneralCode is not persistent yet
        this.em.persist(addr.getUse());
        //since there is a cascade ALL on the adresses relationship addr is now persistent
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("=========================== inside jpahl7patientrespository.savehl7Address(addr)");
    if ((Integer)addr.getId() == null) {
        System.out.println("[[[[[[[[[[[[ about to persist address ]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]");
        this.em.persist(addr);}
    else {
        System.out.println("]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]] about to merge address [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[");
        this.em.merge(addr);}
}
```

The relevant part of HL7Address is now:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "usecode", referencedColumnName = "code", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "usecodesystem", referencedColumnName = "codesystem", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
public HL7GeneralCode use;
```

The relevant part of HL7GeneralCode is now:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "use")
private Set<HL7Address> addresses;
```

The new stack trace can be read [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/wgtZOmTBfbGUk251EyOt?b=2tRMY5jXHbumJQO1rNJq).

How can I resolve this error?

---

### **THIRD EDIT:**

I followed ben75's advice by adding the following code to the save address method:

```
if(addr.getUse() != null && !this.em.contains(addr.getUse())){
    System.out.println("about to this.em.persist(addr.getUse());");
    this.em.persist(addr.getUse());return;
}
```

Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error despite the fact that the stack trace `SYSO` indicates that the above code is running just before the app crashes.

You can read the resulting stack trace [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/JqAVABZR5Wf9IZrXwNDq?b=zohXwp4Ood8T6RIbC1n2).

Comment: What does your `EntityManager` "persist" codes look like?

Comment: @isim I just added the persist code as an edit to the end of my original posting above.  Does this help you?

Comment: All links are broken and this question, although quite useful because of the excellent answer, is of diminished use to others now. A good reason why external links are not to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there are some things to clear out:

1. You have a bidirectional association between HL7GeneralCode(the parent) and HL7Address (the child). If the HL7GeneralCode.addresses is the "inverse" side (mappedBy) then why the owning side HL7Address.use has insertable/updatable false? The owning side should control this association so you should remove the insertable/updatable=false flags.
2. It always makes sense to cascade from the Parent to the Child, not the other way around. But in your use case, you try to persist the Child and automatically persist the Parent too. That's why the CASCADE.ALL on the many to one end doesn't make sense.
3. When using bidirectional associations, both sides are mandatory to be set:

   ```
   HL7Address addr = new HL7Address();
   HL7GeneralCode code = new HL7GeneralCode();
   ...
   code.getAddresses().add(addr);
   addr.setUse(code);
   ```
4. The persist operation is meant to INSERT transient entities, never to merge them or reattach entities. This implies that both the HL7Address and the HL7GeneralCode are new entities when you call your service method. If you have already saved a HL7GeneralCode with the same ID, you will get the primary key constraint violation exception.
5. If the HL7GeneralCode is possible to exist, then you should fetch it from db.

   ```
   HL7GeneralCode code = em.find(HL7GeneralCode, pk);
   HL7Address addr = new HL7Address();
   if(code != null) {
      code = new HL7GeneralCode();
      em.persist(code);    
   }
   code.getAddresses().add(addr);
   addr.setUse(code);            
   em.persist(addr);
   ```

**UPDATE**

6. The HL7Address address doesn't override equals/hashCode so the default object same reference check rule applies. This will ensure we can add/remove addresses from the code.addresses List. In case you change your mind later, make sure you [implement equals and hashCode properly](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/).
7. Although not related to your issue, you might want to use getter/setter instead of making your fields public. This provides better encapsulation and you will avoid mixing setters with public field access.

The savehl7Address method:

```
@Override
public void savehl7Address(HL7Address addr) {
    HL7GeneralCode code = addr.use();
    if(code != null && code.getId()==null){
    //HL7GeneralCode is not persistent. We don't support that
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot persist an adress using a non persistent HL7GeneralCode");
       //In case you'd want to support it
       //code = em.find(HL7GeneralCode, code.getId());
    }
    //Merge the code without any address info        
    //This will ensure we only reattach the code without triggering the address 
    //transitive persistence by reachability
    addr.setUse(null);
    code.getAddresses().remove(addr);
    code = em.merge(code); 

    //Now set the code to the address and vice-versa  
    addr.setUse(code);
    code.getAddresses().add(addr);

    if ((Integer)addr.getId() == null) {
        System.out.println("[[[[[[[[[[[[ about to persist address ]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]");
        em.persist(addr);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]] about to merge address [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[");
        addr = em.merge(addr);
    }       
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. I tried what I understood of your ideas, but it still doesn't resolve the error and I have some questions. For your idea 1, I eliminated `insertable=false` and `updatable=false` from `address`. Still in idea 1, are you saying to change `Address.use` to `OneToMany` with `mappedBy`? And to change `GeneralCode.addresses` to `ManyToOne`? For your idea 2, I still do not have any `cascade` rule set on either side, is this ok? In your idea 4, what specifically should my `savehl7Address()` method look like?.  In your idea 5, why do you create an empty code if retrieved code is NOT null?

Comment: 1. Why did you made the Address as the one side and the Code as the many, if the other way around was the original association logic. In 1. I told you to have the insertable/updatable=true on the many side. If you have many addresses for one code then you should not change the association type. 2. It's better to make it work without cascade first and add it later if it proves to shortcut some steps. In 5. I don't create an empty code. I try to fetch it from DB first. I assumed you might sometimes have the same code shared by multiple addresses. 4. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you.  This seems to work now, but I am going to work with it for a bit to make sure it continues to work before I mark this as answered.  It was throwing errors for a bit due to the fact that addresses in an un-modifiable collection, but I was able to resolve those error.

Comment: Did you replace code.addresses with Collection.unmodifiableList or Arrays.toList? Those methods return a List implementation that's different than an ArrayList. Check code.addresses type. It should be ArrayList for transient entities and PersistentList for persisted ones.

Comment: Well, I am glad I could help.

Comment: Hi @Vlad. I think, in the second section of code, other than `HL7GeneralCode code = em.find(HL7GeneralCode, pk);` the rest should be inside the `if`. And in the third section, if `code` is null, the `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is the `CascadeType.ALL` on the `use` relationship.

What's going on ?

- You have one instance of `HL7GeneralCode` **persistent** in your db. Let's call it : `code1`.
- You create a new `Address` and define the `use` relation with something like :

  `theNewAdress.setUse(code1);`
- You call `savehl7Address(theNewAddress)` and since the address is new you made a call to `persist`. **The problem is that the cascading rule `CascadeType.ALL` will force a call to `persist(code1)` and since code1 is already in the db : crash because of duplicate entry.**

Solution :

Define no cascading rule for the `use` relationship :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "usecode", referencedColumnName = "code", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "usecodesystem", referencedColumnName = "codesystem", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
public HL7GeneralCode use;
```

But you must manage it by hand, especially if there is a use case where the `HL7GeneralCode` used by the address is not already in the db.

Over-simplified solution (so that you can understand the problem) :

```
@Override
public void savehl7Address(HL7Address addr) {
    if(addr.use() != null && addr.use().getId()==null){
        //HL7GeneralCode is not persistent yet
        this.em.persist(addr.use());
        //since there is a cascade ALL on the adresses relationship addr is now persistent
        return;
    }
    if ((Integer)addr.getId() == null) {
        System.out.println("[[[[[[[[[[[[ about to persist address ]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]");
        this.em.persist(addr);}
    else {
        System.out.println("]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]] about to merge address [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[");
        this.em.merge(addr);}
}
```

As you can see this solution is certainly not the best and not production ready. The real solution is to study all your use-case and adapt the cascading rule (on both `use` and `adresses` relationships) accordingly.

In my opinion, the best thing to do is to ensure that the `HL7GeneralCode` is already persistent when you call `savehl7Address` and so something like this is probably a better solution:

```
@Override
public void savehl7Address(HL7Address addr) {
    if(addr.use() != null && addr.use().getId()==null){
        //HL7GeneralCode is not persistent. We don't support that
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot persist an adress using a non persistent HL7GeneralCode");
    }
    if ((Integer)addr.getId() == null) {
        System.out.println("[[[[[[[[[[[[ about to persist address ]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]");
        this.em.persist(addr);}
    else {
        System.out.println("]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]] about to merge address [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[");
        this.em.merge(addr);}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my problem, but your suggestions do not solve my problem. Removing `CascadeType.ALL` from the `use` relationship results in `Address` being saved with a `null` `use` field. Also, `addr.getUse()` does not have a `.getId()` property.  When I replace `addr.getUse().getId()` with `addr.getUse.getCodePk()` or `addr.getId()`, the `address` is still persisted with a `null` `use` field.  I used `SYSO` just prior to calling `savehl7Address(addr)` to confirm there is a valid `use.codePk.getCode()` and `use.codePk.getCodesystem()` even though they are not added to database

Comment: I added a second edit to my original post above further clarifying my problem with additional code.  Does this help you identify the solution to my problem?

Comment: @CodeMed Try this test : `if(addr.getUse() != null && !this.em.contains(addr.getUse())){this.em.persist(addr.use());return;}`

Comment: Thank you for trying, but it still gives the same error after your changes.  I confirmed that it is running your code by adding SYSO as follows: `if(addr.getUse() != null && !this.em.contains(addr.getUse())){System.out.println("about to this.em.persist(addr.getUse());");this.em.persist(addr.getUse());return;}`. The SYSO confirms that it runs your code just before the app crashes.  I uploaded the resulting stack trace as a 3rd edit to my original post above.  It does save the same child entity just before running your code, but that shouldn't matter bcuz child entities come preinstalled.